# System API to see when threads are active

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, darwin, mach

Is there a low-level system API for Linux and for Darwin, to get a "snapshot" of the scheduler, to see which threads were at a given time running (active), preempted, waiting on a resource, or similar?

For example the Ubuntu "System Monitor" has an "Waiting channel" column for processes, is there a way to get a similar output for all threads inside a process?

I have a multi-threaded queuing system where jobs are dispatched to the threads, with a visual timeline showing when the jobs are started/finished. In order to optimize it I want to add some visual indication of when the jobs are actually running (on one processor core for example), vs when they are preempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top -H` shows threads and their states. Following the -H switch in [its source](http://www.unixtop.org/dist/top-3.8beta1.tar.gz) will be one way to find out. From a quick look, the function `int cmd_threads(globalstate *gstate)` in `commands.c` seems to toggle the setting.

UPDATE: Procfs provides that info to user space. `/proc/<pid>/task/<thread-id>/status` gives exactly what you need. That's what `top` uses too. Here is sample output from my system:

```
$ cat /proc/418/task/448/status | grep State
State:  S (sleeping)
```

There's plenty more useful detail under that directory.